# How to make WPF Textbox automaticly scroll down

Tags: .net, wpf, scroll, textbox

I have a `TextBox` in my application for showing progress. I want my `TextBox` to scroll to the bottom of the `TextBox` automaticly.

This is what I have tried:

```
TextBox.ScrollToEnd();

//and 

TextBox.SelectionStart = TextBox.Text.Length;
TextBox.ScrollToCaret();

//and 

TextBoxBase.ScrollToEnd().
```

My xaml code:

```
<TextBox  x:Name="TextBox" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="77" Margin="0,106,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsReadOnly="True" Cursor="Arrow" />
```

I'm new to WPF and explaining code snippets will help me understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextBox.ScrollToEnd()` should work if you set the `AcceptsReturn` property to `true`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox" ... AcceptsReturn="True" />
```